# How does kubernetes help in reducing the cost of hosting?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to understand this hosting and scaling stuffs , say if i have a website with huge traffic on weekends which would require 2 vps at least to handle the load.
we could do either of the 2 things

1. we could simply upgrade to a larger vps plan and forget it, which is an inefficient way and also a costlier option.
2. Making 2 vps and setting up a load balancer and let it handle the traffic between 2 vps just like kubernetes does.

So how are kubernetes helpful then if we are still paying for 2nd vps?
Can kubernetes spin full vps before deploying news pods in it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md) for your Kubernetes cluster which will add or remove nodes on demands.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes can run virtually anywhere -  on bare metal as well as in a private or public cloud.
However, where you choose to run Kubernetes determines the scalability of your Kubernetes cluster.

Deploying Kubernetes on VPS servers requires more effort on your side and the cluster is less scalable compared to managed Kubernetes services such as: [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks) and [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/).

In General, the [Cluster Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler) is available primarily for managed Kubernetes Services (see: [Supported cloud providers](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler#deployment)).

**Cluster Autoscaler**:

> Cluster Autoscaler is a tool that automatically adjusts the size of the Kubernetes cluster when one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - there are pods that failed to run in the cluster due to insufficient resources.
> - there are nodes in the cluster that have been underutilized for an extended period of time and their pods can be placed on other existing nodes.

For VPS, you can still use the [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) (HPA) and [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) (VPA) to optimize the resource utilization of your application.

**Horizontal Pod Autoscaler**:

> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler automatically scales the number of Pods in a replication controller, deployment, replica set or stateful set based on observed CPU utilization (or, with custom metrics support, on some other application-provided metrics).

**Vertical Pod Autoscaler**:

> The Vertical Pod Autoscaler automatically adjust the amount of CPU and memory requested by pods running in the Kubernetes Cluster.